# docbook5 default value for graphic scale

Tags: docbook

I have a docbook xml-document with many graphics. All graphics must be centered and scaled.
The centering is no problem. I added

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="figure.properties">
<xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

to my xsl-stylesheet and converted it with

```
fop -xml my-xml-document.sgm -xsl my-xsl-stylesheet.xsl -pdf my-document.pdf
```

and it works fine.
But I found no solution to set a default scale value in the xsl-stylesheet for the graphics.

How is the solution?

Thanks, M.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `default.image.width` parameter in your XSL customization layer. [See this page](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.75.2/doc/fo/default.image.width.html)